# Can I specify vertices to be unmovable, when sculpting?

Tags: modeling

Couldn't find anything in constraints. Also searched 'lock vertex', 'anchor vertex'.

I now realize my question wasn't completely clear after reading some replies. Sorry about that. I'm starting a model of a river bend and adjacent banks with the intent of creating a semi-photorealistic render. I am a very new to Blender and expect this WIP to remain so for a while, improving as I do.

My plan is to create 3 objects; north bank landscape, river, and south bank landscape. Starting with the south bank object I decided to start with creating a big plane object, subdivided into a pretty fine mesh, and then moved the top vertices to match the river edge. Then I extruded it in Z direction. Now this is where I'd like to lock the original vertices and sculpt the rest. This is to ensure that the planar edge where the bank meets the water remains unchanged, no matter how clumsily I might select vertices.

Comment: Hello, unmovable when you model your object? You could make it invisible

Comment: A lot of techniques can achieve that, depending what's the exact result you want to achieve.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/404048) We still want to help you! Please expand your question a bit.

Comment: If you put the unmovable vertices into a group and then use menu "Mesh :: Show/Hide :: Hide Selected", you can edit the remaining vertices (sculpt or otherwise transform).  After you are satisfied you can then "Mesh :: Show/Hide :: Reveal Hidden" to see the full mesh again.

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/introduction/visibility_masking_face_sets.html) might be a good start.. masking might be what you're after. with any luck someone will demo it for you.

Comment: When you sculpt you can preserve some parts with the Mask brush or with the Face Sets, I don't know if this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, masking the bottom plane of vertices in sculpt mode worked. I discovered that I needed to enable 'Front Face Only' in the mask brush options to prevent the masking from 'bleeding thru' to the other side that i wanted to sculpt, so still learning. Back on course.